# How do i display people who are older than a particular person SQL?

Tags: xml, subquery

What function shall i use to display all those people who are older than a specific person. DOB in my table is given in the format 19-JAN-88

```
select * from student
where 
order by firstname;
```

Comment: As it is nothing to do with xml, please remove that tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from student where DOB > ( select DOB from student where student_name='value')
```

I assume DOB datatype is Date or otherwise, you can use following:

```
select * from student where CONVERT( VARCHAR(30),DOB,105) > ( select CONVERT( VARCHAR(30),DOB,105) from student where student_name='value')
```

Answer (score 0):

What type of date do you have it formatted as? Just because there are various date types.
Is there anyway you can get an AGE rather than a date so it's working with an int rather than a date?

You could potentially make the adjustment in the SELECT statement (instead of select *)

Let's assume DATE which is YYYY-MM-DD (of course it could be date time, etc.)

WHERE date (your_field_name) > (1988-01-19)

Answer (score -1):

If you can't change the dob field into a sensible format then you will need to use the 
str_to_date( your_dob_field, '%d-%b-%y' ) so you would write

select * from student where str_to_date( your_dob_field, '%d-%b-%y' ) < str_to_date( dob_of_student_to_compare_to, '%d-%b-%y' );

Comment: Downvoted.  One, your answer is not formatted according to Stack Overflow standards.  Two, you are assuming that the dob field is varchar.  It might be a date or datetime.  Three, the OP did not specify the database engine, and your answer is only valid for mysql.

Comment: Actually Dan I am answering the question as asked. If you look at the question he has said the format in the DB is 19-Jan-88 which in Mysql would have to be a varchar all the other answers are assuming that the field is a date field which it is not because that is not a native display format.  He asked for the function to use  so I have said what function to use to correctly compare one dob in this format to another.